# Remove order from Field Collection set in form

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) and [Field Collection Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_fieldset) modules to group a set of elements in my form. But what i see in the form is an Order column for the fieldset items, which i would like to hide, as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

I have tried a lot to figure out if i can hide the Order from the backend, but i could not find a setting for it anywhere. So i am now looking forward to use a hook, to hide it. I also checked the field level structure using Devel module and `dpm($form);` but i have no idea on how to accomplish this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just use CSS to hide that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Rupesh suggested in his comment, i was able to use CSS for hiding the Order column in my form:

First, i specified an ID for the fieldset field in my module's **node_form_alter()** function:

```
$form['field_user_details']['#attributes'] = array('id' => 'user_details');
```

Then in my CSS, i used these lines to hide the Order column:

```
#user_details table th:nth-child(2) { display: none; } /* Hide the Order column Label */
#user_details table td.delta-order { display: none; } /* Hide the Order column */
```